# Ios image collision with one imageview

Tags: ios, uiimageview, collision

I am making an app that has 2 UIImageViews but in each image view the image changes 3 times. How can I make it so that if image A collides with image B or C action happens but not with image A and so on. Here is the code for the image changing

ImageView Changing 1

This is a random change

```
Trap.center = CGPointMake(350,220);

Trap1 = rand() %3;
switch (Trap1) {
    case 0:
        Trap.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"];
        break;
    case 1:
        Trap.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2.png"];
        break;
    case 2:
        Trap.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image3.png"];
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
```

ImageView Changing 2

This is set with a swipe and is copied for the other 2 changes.

```
   -(IBAction)Change3:(id)sender{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image4.tif"];
     [Change3 setImage:img];

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a tag to your Trap object. Compare the tags and if they are different, do something.

Set tag:

```
switch (Trap1) {
case 0:
    Trap.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"];
    Trap.tag = 1;
    break;
case 1:
    Trap.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2.png"];
    Trap.tag = 2;
    break;
case 2:
    Trap.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image3.png"];
    Trap.tag = 3;
    break;
default:
    break;
```

}

Compare tags

```
If (trap1.tag != trap2.tag){
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: There is only 1 trap so trap1.tag and trap2.tag will not work. I want it to be if image 1 is the right image and it collides nothing happens but if it is wrong then it runs a command